# Using dynamically created .addEventListener's

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, performance, addeventlistener

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but the found answers on www didn't reply my specific question, or I'm simply lacking the terms to find the correct answer, if so, I would be happy to be guided to the right direction. :)

My issue is, that I fetch an array from a .json file, similar to this:

```
[
    "Ben Berry",
    "Susan Boile",
    "Jerry Smith",
    ...
]
```

and make a local variable copy of it, which will be used for all next script.js work.

Lets also imagine, that this list is gigantic.

Inside my HTML, I'm dynamically displaying all these elements using list elements in an unordered list.

Now, if somebody clicks on one of these li's, it should be removed from the DOM and the local variable copy of the element should be removed too.

This could of course be done with an HTML attribute inside the li tag -> `onclick=function()` but I feel more comfortable to use the addEventListener method.

These listeners could easily be added to each one of them by looping trough the whole array using .forEach and adding an eventListener to each li.

However, what happens if I sort the list now alphabetically, by first name or last name, over and over again. This would lead to call the function containing this .forEach loop also over and over again.

Wouldn't this procedure create billions of billions of billions(no pun intended) eventListeners in the memory which becomes a performance issue? If so, what would be the best procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is instead of adding an event to each items, add the event to the parent of the items and look for which item was clicked. Here is an example :

```js
function setupListListener ()
{
  // Get the list
  const list = document.querySelector( 'ul' );
  
  // Add click event
  list.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    
    // Get the clicked element
    let target = event.target;
    
    // If it is not an item, return
    if ( target.nodeName !== 'LI' ) return;
    
    // Do something with the item li
    console.log( 'Item : ', target );
  
  });
}

// Usage example
setupListListener();
```

```css
*
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul
{
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

li
{
  width: 90%;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about this way! But is there then a performance issue if the addEventListeners would be created via my method?

Answer (score 1):

Using onclick is legacy JS from the late 90's, so it's a good thing that you're partial to `addEventListener` solutions: your initial idea was good, but add that listener to the document, instead of to each li, and then check to see which element generated the event:

```
const ulElement = document.getElementByIdOrsomeCSSQueryOrSomething(...);

...

document.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  // Only do things if the event source is an <li>, which we know
  // is the case if its parent node is our <ul> element:
  if (evt.target.parentNode === ulElement) {

    // remove the name from the list...
    let name = evt.target.textContent;
    removeName(name);

    // ... and remove the <li> from the DOM
    ulElement.removeChild(evt.target);

  }
});
```

(Alternatively, you can also add the click handling to the list itself, but if you ever want to swap entire lists in/out, this code just requires updating the conditional, rather than adding and removing event listeners as you show/hide lists on the page)

Comment: Just have to be careful if there are other elements in the `<li>`...they could become target

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about this way! But is there then a performance issue if the addEventListeners would be created via my method?
And sorry that I opted for the other answer as solution, I guess he could use those small points more than you, but still gratefull for your time taken!
@charlietfl yes I have placed now an if statement with two conditionals that It should only be accepted under specific conditions.

Comment: If I cared about points, I shouldn't be here. The trick is that you can issue this addEventListener (singular, rather than plural) at any point after you know what your "top" `<ul>` is. It doesn't matter if it already has '<li>' in it or not.